# PowerShell Script- Copy Ad Member o

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-3.0

I wrote this script to copy user AD 'member of' from one user to another which works perfectly fine. I have updated the file to change to an executable file (.exe) which ran but won't do the job ( i need to use a code that will echo the script rather than closing it when script is completed) as I couldn't see the error for the .exe when completed.

Script is working without changing the to exe. Find attached script ( please do let me knw if you identify anything to add to the code to make it work in .exe format and also to echo words in the code)

```
# import the Active Directory module in order to be able to use get-ADuser and Add-AdGroupMembe cmdlet
import-Module ActiveDirectory

$usrCopyFrom = Read-Host -Prompt "CopyFromUser"
$usrCopyTo = Read-Host -Prompt "CopyToUser"
$CopyFromUser.MemberOf | Where{$CopyToUser.MemberOf -notcontains $_} |  Add-ADGroupMember -Members $CopyToUser
```

Comment: Use Try...Catch along with `-ErrorAction Stop` to trap the error and you can pause the script in the Catch block to display the error.

Comment: Do you mean edit as below? @Aserre

`$CopyFromUser.MemberOf | Where{$CopyToUser.MemberOf -notcontains $_} |  Add-ADGroupMember -Members $CopyToUser -ErrorAction Stop`

Comment: no, I just removed the `bash` tag. Your problem is related to `powershell`, not `bash`. `bash` is a scripting language for Linux/Unix platforms.

Comment: Yes, I am aware, -- Just added it as it says choose 5 Tag.. and btw i don't understand what you mean by NO